# Problem with bs4 while trying to get an in stock notification

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want my code to return the words in the "ncss-btn-primary-dark  btn-lg" class in this website: https://www.nike.com/it/launch/t/womens-air-jordan-3-sp-a-ma-maniere
the problem is that my code always returns none instead of returning "avvisami" or in other cases "Articolo esaurito"

The Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nike.com/it/launch/t/womens-air-jordan-3-sp-a-ma-maniere'

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36"}

def stock_check():
  webpage = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')
  stock = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'ncss-btn-primary-dark  btn-lg'}).get_text()
  print(stock)



stock_check()
```

Right now it returns  `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'` but if you take away the `.get_text` it just returns none

Comment: Hi @Ricccccccccc. Welcome to the community. The element you are referring is inside `::before` and `::after` tag. Usually the elements inside these tags are loaded by some java script or seperate api call. Most probably that is the reason Beautiful Soup is not able to find the element . Since `soup.find('div', {'class' : 'ncss-btn-primary-dark  btn-lg'})` is returning `none` you are getting this exception.

Comment: @Roy So what I'm thinking is that I need to use selenium right?

Comment: Yes with selenium you should be able to get the required data. It will be little bit slower compared to beautifulsoup though.

Comment: You are scraping Nike, Nike has anti-bot implemented on the site. Can you try to print(soup)? I am assuming you are encountering the anti-bot, hence you are not getting the page.